# Ionic Qr scan tutorial

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, qr-code

I am trying to scan a QR code using `phonegap-plugin-qrscanner`. I follow the tutorial steps but, the camera is not open in the device.

It is my code:

```
constructor(private qrScanner: QRScanner) {}

this.qrScanner.prepare()
    .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
      console.log('QRScanStatus status:');
      console.log(status);
      if(status.authorized) {
               // start scanning
        let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
         console.log('Scanned something', text);

         this.qrScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
         scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
       });
        this.qrScanner.show();
      }else if(status.denied) {
        console.log('Status denied ...');
      }else{
        console.log('Otro estado ...');
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('Error atrapado: ', e);
    });
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to use the API of another plugin, namely [`cordova-plugin-qrscanner`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/)

So my suggestion is to either, place your code in a function and install [`cordova-plugin-qrscanner`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/):

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-qrscanner
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/qr-scanner
```

or take a look at the documentation for [`phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/) and change you code accordingly.

Comment: Why barcode ? Ionic have a plugin for QR codes, [see](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/).

Comment: Read your own question, you say that you are trying to use `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`. But you are trying to use the API for `cordova-plugin-qrscanner`. That wont work.

Comment: Sorry, was an error typo. I think that the camera is open but, is behind of my view ...

Comment: Wrap all of your scanner-related code in a function. And call that function when you need it.

Comment: @robbannn - what does `@ionic-native/qr-scanner` do for the install?  I am running an Ionic v1 Tabs app and managed to get the `cordova-plugin-qrscanner` to work without installing the `ionic-native` part.  Granted, I had to jump through some creative hoops because applying `background:transparent` to a few Ionic created DIVs was challenging - but none the less, I got it working.  Wondering what the `ionic-native` provides?